Using xorg.conf creating 2 x servers?
So I have 2 displaylink displays, each shows as a framebuffer device, fb0, and fb1. I am using raspberry pi os, and it will show on one display, but the other is blank, however if I move the cursor over, it shows as an x, which I think indicates it is a blank xserver. I have tried all sorts of different xorg.conf variations, and tried to enable xinemera which does nothing and does not appear at all in the log when enabled. I can address each display using DISPLAY=:0.1 or 0, and lets me open apps. if I use DISPLAY=0.1 xrandr I get details on one of the displays, but they seem separate.
my xorg.conf:
Section "Device"
Identifier "FBDEV 0"
Driver "fbdev"
Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
EndSection


Section "Device"
Identifier "FBDEV 1"
Driver "fbdev"
Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "DL1"
Device "FBDEV 0"
Monitor "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "DL2"
Device "FBDEV 1"
Monitor "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "Default Layout"
Screen 0 "DL1" 0 0
Screen 1 "DL2" RightOf "DL1"
Option "Xinemera" "on"
EndSection

and the corresponding log file:
X.Org X Server 1.20.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   634.407] Build Operating System: linux Raspbian
[   634.407] Current Operating System: Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64
[   634.407] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=0  smsc95xx.macaddr=E4:5F:01:AF:76:E0 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=84c4adaf-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
[   634.408] Build Date: 29 April 2024  03:20:14PM
[   634.408] xorg-server 2:1.20.11-1+rpt3+deb11u13 (https://www.debian.org/support)
[   634.408] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[   634.408]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   634.408] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   634.408] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jul 15 14:47:23 2024
[   634.409] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   634.409] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   634.409] (==) ServerLayout "Default Layout"
[   634.409] (**) |-->Screen "DL1" (0)
[   634.409] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[   634.410] (**) |   |-->Device "FBDEV 0"
[   634.410] (**) |-->Screen "DL2" (1)
[   634.410] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor1"
[   634.411] (**) |   |-->Device "FBDEV 1"
[   634.412] (**) Option "Debug" "dmabuf_capable"
[   634.412] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   634.412] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   634.412] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   634.412] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   634.412] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" does not exist.
[   634.412]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   634.412] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   634.412]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   634.412] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   634.412]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   634.412] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   634.412]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   634.412] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[   634.412]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   634.412] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   634.412]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   634.412] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   634.412]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   634.412] (==) FontPath set to:
        built-ins
[   634.412] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   634.412] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   634.413] (II) Loader magic: 0x20cf40
[   634.413] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   634.413]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   634.413]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[   634.413]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   634.413]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   634.415] (++) using VT number 7

[   634.415] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   634.419] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   634.420] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   634.421] (II) no primary bus or device found
[   634.421]    falling back to /sys/devices/platform/gpu/drm/card1
[   634.421] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   634.421] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   634.425] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   634.425]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[   634.425]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   634.425] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   634.425] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   634.426] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   634.426]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 0.5.0
[   634.426]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   634.426]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   634.426] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   634.426] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   634.426] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   634.426] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   634.426] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   634.427] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   634.427]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 0.0.2
[   634.427]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   634.427] (II) FBDEV(0): using /dev/fb0
[   634.427] (II) FBDEV(1): using /dev/fb1
[   634.427] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "DL1" for depth/fbbpp 16/16
[   634.427] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 16, (==) framebuffer bpp 16
[   634.428] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 565
[   634.428] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   634.428] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   634.428] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: udlfb (video memory: 676kB)
[   634.428] (DB) xf86MergeOutputClassOptions unsupported bus type 0
[   634.428] (**) FBDEV(0): Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
[   634.428] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[   634.428] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[   634.428] (II) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1440x240 (pitch 1440)
[   634.428] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 27.0 MHz, 15.1 kHz, 57.9 Hz
[   634.428] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0   27.00  1440 1770 1774 1792  240 254 256 260 -hsync +vsync -csync (15.1 kHz b)
[   634.428] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   634.428] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   634.428] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   634.429] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   634.429] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   634.429]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[   634.429]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   634.429] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[   634.429] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[   634.429] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[   634.430] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[   634.430] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   634.430]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.1.0
[   634.430]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   634.430] (II) FBDEV(1): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "DL2" for depth/fbbpp 16/16
[   634.430] (==) FBDEV(1): Depth 16, (==) framebuffer bpp 16
[   634.430] (==) FBDEV(1): RGB weight 565
[   634.430] (==) FBDEV(1): Default visual is TrueColor
[   634.430] (==) FBDEV(1): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   634.430] (II) FBDEV(1): hardware: udlfb (video memory: 676kB)
[   634.430] (DB) xf86MergeOutputClassOptions unsupported bus type 0
[   634.430] (**) FBDEV(1): Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
[   634.430] (II) FBDEV(1): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[   634.430] (II) FBDEV(1): checking modes against monitor...
[   634.430] (II) FBDEV(1): Virtual size is 1440x240 (pitch 1440)
[   634.431] (**) FBDEV(1):  Built-in mode "current": 27.0 MHz, 15.1 kHz, 57.9 Hz
[   634.431] (II) FBDEV(1): Modeline "current"x0.0   27.00  1440 1770 1774 1792  240 254 256 260 -hsync +vsync -csync (15.1 kHz b)
[   634.431] (==) FBDEV(1): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   634.431] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   634.431] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   634.431] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   634.431] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   634.431]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[   634.431]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   634.431] (**) FBDEV(1): using shadow framebuffer
[   634.431] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[   634.431] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[   634.432] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[   634.432] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   634.432]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.1.0
[   634.432]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   634.432] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[   634.433] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[   634.433] (==) FBDEV(1): Backing store enabled
[   634.433] (==) FBDEV(1): DPMS enabled
[   634.433] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[   634.434] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[   634.435] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[   634.436] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[   634.437] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[   634.437] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   634.438] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[   634.438] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[   634.439] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[   634.439] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[   634.440] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[   634.440] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[   634.441] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[   634.441] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[   634.442] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[   634.442] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   634.443] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   634.443] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[   634.444] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[   634.444] (II) Initializing extension Present
[   634.445] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[   634.445] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[   634.445] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[   634.446] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   634.446] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[   634.446] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   634.446] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   634.446] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[   634.523] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[   634.523] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[   634.523] (II) AIGLX: Screen 1 is not DRI2 capable
[   634.536] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[   634.536] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 1
[   634.536] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   634.537] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[   634.537] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[   634.537] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[   634.638] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075 (/dev/input/event4)
[   634.639] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   634.639] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[   634.639] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[   634.643] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   634.643]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 0.30.0
[   634.643]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   634.643]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[   634.643] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075'
[   634.643] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: always reports core events
[   634.643] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[   634.643] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   634.655] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   634.655] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: device is a keyboard
[   634.656] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: device removed
[   634.676] (II) libinput: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: needs a virtual subdevice
[   634.676] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fe9c0000.xhci/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.4/1-1.1.4:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0003/0003:046D:4075.0005/input/input29/event4"
[   634.676] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075" (type: MOUSE, id 6)
[   634.676] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   634.676] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   634.676] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   634.676] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   634.684] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   634.684] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: device is a keyboard
[   634.689] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/event5)
[   634.689] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   634.689] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Mouse'
[   634.689] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: always reports core events
[   634.689] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[   634.689] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   634.698] (II) event5  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   634.698] (II) event5  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: device is a pointer
[   634.699] (II) event5  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: device removed
[   634.732] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fe9c0000.xhci/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.4/1-1.1.4:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0003/0003:046D:4091.0006/input/input30/event5"
[   634.732] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 7)
[   634.732] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   634.732] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   634.732] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   634.732] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   634.740] (II) event5  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   634.741] (II) event5  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: device is a pointer
[   634.745] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/mouse2)
[   634.745] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   634.745] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   634.749] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 (/dev/input/event2)
[   634.749] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: Applying InputClass "libinput touchscreen catchall"
[   634.749] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163'
[   634.749] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: always reports core events
[   634.749] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[   634.749] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   634.757] (II) event2  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[   634.757] (II) event2  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: device is a touch device
[   634.758] (II) event2  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: device removed
[   634.772] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fe9c0000.xhci/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.2/1-1.2.2:1.0/0003:0EEF:C001.0001/input/input14/event2"
[   634.772] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 8)
[   634.772] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   634.772] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   634.772] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   634.772] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   634.780] (II) event2  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[   634.780] (II) event2  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: device is a touch device
[   634.784] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   634.784] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   634.784] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   634.788] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN (/dev/input/event3)
[   634.788] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   634.788] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN'
[   634.788] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: always reports core events
[   634.788] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[   634.788] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   634.796] (II) event3  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   634.797] (II) event3  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: device is a pointer
[   634.797] (II) event3  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: device removed
[   634.812] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fe9c0000.xhci/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.2/1-1.2.2:1.0/0003:0EEF:C001.0001/input/input16/event3"
[   634.812] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[   634.812] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   634.812] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   634.812] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   634.812] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   634.820] (II) event3  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   634.821] (II) event3  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: device is a pointer
[   634.825] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN (/dev/input/js0)
[   634.825] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   634.825] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   634.828] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   634.828] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   634.828] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   634.832] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 (/dev/input/event6)
[   634.832] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: Applying InputClass "libinput touchscreen catchall"
[   634.832] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163'
[   634.832] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: always reports core events
[   634.832] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[   634.832] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   634.841] (II) event6  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[   634.841] (II) event6  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: device is a touch device
[   634.842] (II) event6  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: device removed
[   634.860] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fe9c0000.xhci/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4.2/1-1.2.4.2:1.0/0003:0EEF:C002.0004/input/input26/event6"
[   634.860] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 10)
[   634.860] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   634.860] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   634.860] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   634.860] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   634.868] (II) event6  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[   634.869] (II) event6  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163: device is a touch device
[   634.873] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 (/dev/input/mouse3)
[   634.873] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   634.873] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   634.877] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN (/dev/input/event7)
[   634.877] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   634.877] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN'
[   634.877] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: always reports core events
[   634.877] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[   634.877] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   634.886] (II) event7  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   634.887] (II) event7  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: device is a pointer
[   634.887] (II) event7  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: device removed
[   634.908] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fe9c0000.xhci/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4.2/1-1.2.4.2:1.0/0003:0EEF:C002.0004/input/input28/event7"
[   634.908] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[   634.908] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   634.908] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   634.908] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   634.908] (**) eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   634.916] (II) event7  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   634.917] (II) event7  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN: device is a pointer
[   634.921] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN (/dev/input/js1)
[   634.922] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   634.922] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   634.925] (II) config/udev: Adding input device eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch P80H32 8032 v01 k4.08.163 UNKNOWN (/dev/input/mouse4)
[   634.925] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   634.925] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   634.928] (II) config/udev: Adding input device vc4-hdmi-0 (/dev/input/event0)
[   634.928] (**) vc4-hdmi-0: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   634.928] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'vc4-hdmi-0'
[   634.928] (**) vc4-hdmi-0: always reports core events
[   634.928] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[   634.928] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   634.931] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi-0: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Pointingstick
[   634.932] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi-0: device is a pointer
[   634.932] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi-0: device is a keyboard
[   634.934] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi-0: device removed
[   634.948] (II) libinput: vc4-hdmi-0: needs a virtual subdevice
[   634.948] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0/input12/event0"
[   634.948] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "vc4-hdmi-0" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[   634.948] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   634.948] (**) vc4-hdmi-0: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   634.948] (**) vc4-hdmi-0: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   634.948] (**) vc4-hdmi-0: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   634.952] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi-0: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Pointingstick
[   634.953] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi-0: device is a pointer
[   634.953] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi-0: device is a keyboard
[   634.956] (II) config/udev: Adding input device vc4-hdmi-1 (/dev/input/event1)
[   634.956] (**) vc4-hdmi-1: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   634.956] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'vc4-hdmi-1'
[   634.956] (**) vc4-hdmi-1: always reports core events
[   634.956] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[   634.956] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   634.960] (II) event1  - vc4-hdmi-1: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Pointingstick
[   634.961] (II) event1  - vc4-hdmi-1: device is a pointer
[   634.961] (II) event1  - vc4-hdmi-1: device is a keyboard
[   634.962] (II) event1  - vc4-hdmi-1: device removed
[   634.980] (II) libinput: vc4-hdmi-1: needs a virtual subdevice
[   634.980] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/soc/fef05700.hdmi/rc/rc1/input13/event1"
[   634.980] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "vc4-hdmi-1" (type: MOUSE, id 13)
[   634.980] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   634.980] (**) vc4-hdmi-1: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   634.980] (**) vc4-hdmi-1: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   634.980] (**) vc4-hdmi-1: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   634.984] (II) event1  - vc4-hdmi-1: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Pointingstick
[   634.985] (II) event1  - vc4-hdmi-1: device is a pointer
[   634.985] (II) event1  - vc4-hdmi-1: device is a keyboard
[   635.005] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"

there is a tad more but doesnt seem relevant

It's Xinerama, not "Xinemera".

@Peterdagrape does the problem go away after fixing the typo indicated by telcoM?

@JeffSchaller Hello, I thought I had replied, I fixed the typo and it enabled the second display to connect properly, however my issue isn't fully solved I think
when I open windows, the applications do not show the top bar, by that I mean the bar that has the minimise/maximise/close buttons, they just dont appear, and I cannot resize windows, the cursor goes to an x when I leave the window

@telcoM Thank you for that, it helped a lot, cannot believe I didn't notice that

It sounds to me like this particular question could be closed as a typo, then, and you could open a new question with the new situation and problem?

@JeffSchaller yes, thank you, good idea
